# How do I get the Raw, Pitch and Yaw data from an Android device?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to write an app for my Android 11 smartphone that uses the sensor for the device orientation. The API (I use MAUI Visual Studio 2022) provides me with a quaternion that describes the orientation of the device. This quaternion is formed from the three rotation angles (Yaw, Pitch, Roll) and has four components (X, Y, Z, W).

Due to this conversion, it is no longer possible to determine the original angles (Yaw, Pitch, Roll). But that's exactly what I want to use! My question now is, how do I get to the angles Yaw, Pitch and Roll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, it works fine:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles